# QGIS Field calculator preview is different to field value when identifying neighbor polygons to list and count in attribute field?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, nearest-neighbor

I am using Field Calculator to identify neighboring polygons and count them. However, the Field Calculator preview value is not the value going into the Attribute field (as per images), unless only one row is selected.
Code being used for counting neighbor polygons can be either:

```
aggregate(
  layer:='SA2_2011_subset_neighbour',
  aggregate:='count',
  expression:=$id,
  filter:=touches($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

OR

```
aggregate(
  layer:='SA2_2011_subset_neighbour',
  aggregate:='count',
  expression:=$id,
  filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

Btw: Intersects includes the parent polygon in the count.

Code being used for listing the neighboring polygons can be either:

```
aggregate(
  layer:='SA2_2011_subset_neighbour',
  aggregate:='concatenate',
  expression:=SA2_MAIN11,
  concatenator:=', ',
  filter:=touches($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

OR

```
aggregate(
  layer:='SA2_2011_subset_neighbour',
  aggregate:='concatenate',
  expression:=SA2_MAIN11,
  concatenator:=', ',
  filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

OR

```
aggregate(
  layer:='SA2_2011_subset_neighbour',
  aggregate:='concatenate',
  expression:=SA2_MAIN11,
  concatenator:=', ',
  filter:=intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(@parent),1))
 )
```

All have the same issue.
[image: Neighboring polygon list incorrect, different from Field Calculator preview]
[image: Neighboring polygon count incorrect, different from Field Calculator preview]

Comment: I can't replicate the problem with my datasets, can you share the data?